# How do I create a dynamic table of the top 23 ranked numbers from another table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a ranked table of the frequency of a data table:

[image: Original Data Table]

I want to create another dynamic table (the values will change with new data added) of the top 23 ranked values from the data table, then the second ranked 23 numbers (24-46) and finally the last ranked 23 numbers (47-69).

[image: Count_Rank Table]

How do I achieve this in Excel? My issue is that the table values all change with new data added so it's not static.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshots of how the data table is laid out and how you want the data ranked?  Also what have you tried?

Comment: Chris, thanks for taking a ok at this. Here is a sample screen shot.

Comment: I tried Vlookup, index but they all require a static cell to pick number from but this table changes with a count increase, which changes the ranking order. It is this changing ranking and its corresponding numbers from data table that I want to capture in the blank table.

Comment: Sorry but this is a question which could lead to a range of answers depending on the nature of the data.  What are the numbers?  Ranking them could be made different if they were break scores in games of snooker to if they were numbers randomly picked from a range.  Do tied ranking numbers need to be grouped?  If so, I could be wrong but, I am not sure this can be done without VBA.  If tied ranks can be ranked in a certain number order then I am sure it could be done with `INDEX` and `MATCH`. Can you give us a clue on how you **need** them ranked?

Comment: Also you said more data will be added over time.  Is each column an addition or is there some other way the data is arranged?  Will each column have a maximum of 22 numbers as they are now?

Comment: Chris, the raw data are numbers (1-69) associated with an assigned experiment result. Using data array, I have ranked them based on occurrences. The table is a screen grab and got cutoff on #22. The associated numbers tied to the ranking is what I am interested in capturing (dynamically)  into the empty table shown. Of these rankings I want to capture and populate the left cells of blank table with the top ranked 23 numbers and so on... as indicated above. Experiment is continuous so rankings will change daily and I need to capture numbers as they change.